# Three.js Can fog be applied to area rather than distance from camera?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Imagine a scenario where you have a very large THREE.PlaneGeometry simulating the floor, and you have a camera added to the scene at a random position.

If I manually adjust the near and far values of the fog I can somehow hide the outside of the plane making the impression that is infinite.
So far, so good.

The problem is, what if I make my camera fly around the scene to random positions within the plane? If the random point is close enough to the outside of the plane, the fog won't disguise the end of the plane, because the fog is always based of the camera position.

So my question is, how can we achieve a fog effect only when you're close enough to the limits of the plane?

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrevenancio/t3mtb8wv/) to illustrate my idea.

Comment: How about moving the plane with your camera, so the camera is always in the center of the plane?

Comment: If I do that though the camera and the plane are moving, it's as nothing had happen correct? The objective it to make it look like you're flying over a terrain, but if you go outside the bounds you just enter a "mist" zone. I though about creating a PointCloud particle system where the further away from the scene origin the more dense the particle system is... but this is just too much on the GPU right?

Comment: Your terrain geometry or material likely repeats ( or you can make it seamless), so if the camera gets too far away from the origin, you can shift the terrain geometry by a multiple of the repeat pattern.

Comment: I'm doing that already and swaping textures as I move, but I do have a finite number of textures that make a bigger image. Image Google maps for instance. Its just a radius around a center point where you can fly over. Anyway, I think my question is answeared with a NO :) just far and near can be changed in the fog. thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough in-depth knowledge about how the fog system works, so please if someone can correct me that would be amazing.

I guess fog only renders on camera and you cannot apply that to, let's say, an object or neither you can create a fog object (for example a cube made by fog) unless you use shaders which can make the object look like "fog", however if you go into the object you won't be able to see the fog anymore (or it will not render as expected)

What you can do however is to change dynamically the fog rendering based on your camera position, more is the distance you go far from the center, closer the fog renders to the camera. This is pretty much easily achievable by doing a simple subtraction (X - distance from the Plane center) where X equals to maximum distance the camera can reach.

The distance from the center on the XY plane is easy thing too, if you position the center of the plane at 0,0 you know automatically the X and Y coordinates where your camera is at. Then you can just calculate the hypotenuse relative to the X and Y axis (see below my gif).

[image: Hypotenuse on XY]